# Javascript function is not working properly in Master pages

Tags: asp.net

`document.getelementbyid('txtbox')` is not working when I used in content page as it is working in the normal web page. The value is null when it is used in contentpage. Plz anybody help me

Comment: Are you sure the id of the textbox is txtbox and is placed in the content page itself?

Comment: S... It is in content page only.

Comment: I recommend you to use some tool like IE Development toolbar or Firebug to see how looks like your rendered html and to test your scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id will have changed, you can use something like:

document.getelementbyid(<%=txtTextBox.ClientID%>).value

or you can view the source to get the id in the hopes that it will not change again.

If you have the option I'd switch to some other engine, such as asp.net mvc where you have control over the HTML.

Comment: ASP.NET 4 will feature better support via the new ClientIDMode: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/default.aspx#_TOC3_5

Answer (score 2):

When the page renders, if the textBox is under another control, the Id tends to change.
You can use the `ClientId` property:

```
document.getElementById("<%= txtbox.ClientID %>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this article

[Control ID Naming in Content Pages](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/master-pages/tutorial-05-cs.aspx)

> ASP.NET allows certain controls to be
>   denoted as naming containers. A naming
>   container serves as a new ID
>   namespace. Any server controls that
>   appear within the naming container
>   have their rendered id value prefixed
>   with the ID of the naming container
>   control.
>
> Naming containers not only change the
>   rendered id attribute value, but also
>   affect how the control may be
>   programmatically referenced from the
>   ASP.NET page's code-behind class. The
>   FindControl("controlID") method is
>   commonly used to programmatically
>   reference a Web control. However,
>   FindControl does not penetrate through
>   naming containers. Consequently, you
>   cannot directly use the
>   Page.FindControl method to reference
>   controls within a GridView or other
>   naming container.
>
> Master pages and ContentPlaceHolders
>   are both implemented as naming
>   containers.